# Friends app missing on ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, social, web-feed

I recently installed 13.04 and successfully updated the whole OS. There was this friends app that came with Ubuntu to replace Gwibber, but now its gone and can't find it anywhere.

Comment: What is that app named ? Please explain to us, we dont know what application you mean

Comment: sudo apt-get install friends-app

Answer (score 6):

### How to fix your problem:

Open up the program named "terminal" on Ubuntu, and type this:

`sudo apt-get install friends-app -y`

This will install the friends-app, and it will come back.

~Regards

Comment: Maybe this is a bug, since I don't have Friends preinstalled as well, but this command solves it all

Answer (score 0):

Unity has a social lens installed by default in Raring. While you can’t tweet from it you can view statuses, mentions, messages, etc.

[Facebook: Visit this link for more info](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/04/gwibber-not-in-ubuntu-13-04-install-friends)

[Alternately you can check this out](http://www.webupd8.org/2013/04/install-friends-app-gwibber-rewritten.html)

Install Friends App (Gwibber rewritten in QML):

Ubuntu 13.04 Raring Ringtail: You can install Friends via command line:

`sudo apt-get install friends-app`